# Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'redis'

Tags: php, docker, redis, debian, containers

I want to set php.ini to use Redis as session handler. I did it this way:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = tcp://172.17.0.2:6379
```

My Php application and Redis are running in 2 different containers.
This is the code I'm trying to run in Php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
}
?>
```

Due to my searchs I found that I should install:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-redis
```

but `E: Unable to locate package php5-redis`
I've also tried: `php-redis`, `php7-redis`, `php7.4-redis` and the same result.
Resutls for `apt-cache search php | grep -i redis` is:

```
libphp-predis - Flexible and feature-complete PHP client library for the Redis key-value store
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using and on what OS, Ubuntu or Debian, which version ? Try `php -v`. Also list all available packages `apt-cache search php | grep -i redis` to see which one you should install.

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Php 7 and debian
Question updated for apt-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the `pecl` to install redis:

```
pecl install redis
```

More details is [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis)

If you are using docker insert into Dockerfile:

```
RUN pecl install redis \
&& docker-php-ext-enable redis
```